# Excel VBA iterate through sheets and change cells to reflect summary sheet

Tags: excel, macros, vba

So I am new to VBA and trying to write a piece of code to increase my efficiency. I am trying to iterate through 66 different sheets (named 1, 2, 3, etc.) and change the values of certain cells to reflect values listed in a summary sheet. I want to essentially iterate down by one row in the summary sheet for every sheet in the workbook. I tried to record a macro and write something based on that, but my solution doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

*Updated code, but something still isn't working. I think it may be because I am not properly selecting the sheet that I want to make the changes in?

**Edit2: The code works now- I guess I had to put the first 66 sheets at the beginning of the workbook, the macro was trying to iterate through other protected sheets. Thanks for the help.

```
Sub Macro6()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
'Set WS_Count to the number of sheets with CPT data
WS_Count = 66
For i = 1 To WS_Count
Sheets(i).Activate
Sheets(i).Select
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R[" & (17 + i) & "]C[1]"
Range("F6").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R[" & (14 + i) & "]C[4]"
Range("H6").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R[" & (14 + i) & "]C[3]"
Range("I6").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R[" & (14 + i) & "]C[3]"
Range("L6").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R[" & (14 + i) & "]C[8]"
Range("M6").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R[" & (14 + i) & "]C[9]"
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "='Data Input'!R["& (17+i) & "]C[1]"
```

Etc.

No need to select the cells before adding the formula

EDIT: try not using RC notation (you might need to adjust the numbers a little)

```
Sub Macro6()
    Const WS_Count As Long = 66 'number of sheets with CPT data
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        With Sheets(i)
            .Range("A2").Formula = "='Data Input'!A" & (17 + i)
            .Range("F6").Formula = "='Data Input'!D" & (14 + i)
            .Range("H6").Formula = "='Data Input'!C" & (14 + i)
            .Range("I6").Formula = "='Data Input'!C" & (14 + i)
            .Range("L6").Formula = "='Data Input'!H" & (14 + i)
            .Range("M6").Formula = "='Data Input'!I" & (14 + i)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have made the change but it is not working still - do I have to change how I reference the Sheets as well?

Comment: Okay I found my first problem - I needed to take out the second i = in my for loop.